# TCP connection with a fake source IP address

Tags: python, tcp

I want to "establish" a TCP connection to a server with a fake sender IP address by using Python 2.6 on Windows 7.

Is this possible without a proxy/Tor?

I understand that I won't get a response, I'm only interested in sending an HTTP GET request to mimic a DDOS attack on my web server.

Comment: If you just want to test on your own server, then what difference does it make whether the IP address is real or not?

Comment: This is called IP spoofing, but you're going to have some difficulties: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180878/spoofing-the-origination-ip-address-of-an-http-request

Comment: @Kylotan: Because that my web server has a feature that allows multiple clients to make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

You can only send packets with [scapy library](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414025/is-there-a-python-library-than-can-simulate-network-traffic-from-different-addre). But packet will be drop by kernel or filter by NAT, FIREWAL or ISP.

Answer (score 1):

you can send TCP SYN packets to the server to initiate a handshake with the server to start a connection, but as you are using fake IPs the SYN-ACK packets sent from the server will be sent somewhere else and so you won't be able to acknowledge the server and finally start the connection.
you better read more about the tcp handshake and the SYN cookies