# send http request from different IP address

Tags: http, dynamic, request, ip, send

I am running website on windows based machine and I want to call service which is hosted on another server at another network.

When I send request to connect service, it use my server Ip address.

is there any way I can send request everytime from different IP address ?

Thanks
Yatin Thakur

Comment: Did you get success on this task?

Comment: no. still looking for assistance.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414025/is-there-a-python-library-than-can-simulate-network-traffic-from-different-addre